# YouTube showinfo parameter not working

Tags: iframe, youtube

According to the [YouTube docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters) for the `showinfo` parameter:

> Setting the parameter's value to 0 causes the player to not display information like the video title and uploader before the video starts playing.

So why does the title still show in the code below? Note that I'm not using any other parameters that could cause a conflict (e.g. `modestbranding`).

```html
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fVH2lJeZVGU?showinfo=0">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Showinfo` doesnot work like that.

Refer to the defined method help:

> Setting the parameter's value to 0 causes the player to not display
>   information like the video title and uploader before the video starts
>   playing. If the player is loading a playlist, and you explicitly set
>   the parameter value to 1, then, upon loading, the player will also
>   display thumbnail images for the videos in the playlist. Note that
>   this functionality is only supported for the AS3 player.

Comment: Ah...the key is that it's only supported in the AS3 player...which is all but deprecated. I didn't see that. Thanks!